# Почему не работает код? Что я не так делаю? JS

Tags: javascript, html

**Код:**

```js
function valid(regForm) {
  var error = false;
  var name = regForm.name.value;
  var pass = regForm.password.value;
  var rePass = regForm.rePassword.value;
  var email = regForm.email.value;
  var gender = regForm.gender.value;

  if (name == "" || name = " ") {
    error = "Вы не ввели свое имя";
  }
  if (error) {
    alert(error);
  } else {
    window.location = "https//:google.com";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" , method="post" , name="regForm" , id="regForm">
  <label for="name">Имя:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" , id="name" , placeholder="Введите имя"><br><br>
  <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" , id="password" , placeholder="Введите пароль"><br><br>
  <label for="rePassword">Проверка пароля:</label>
  <input type="password" name="rePassword" , id="rePassword" , placeholder="Повторите пароль"><br><br>
  <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" , id="email" , placeholder="Введите E-mail"><br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" , id="male" , value="Мужской">
  <label for="male">Мужской</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" , id="female" , value="Женский">
  <label for="female">Женский</label><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Готово!" name="button" id="button" onclick="valid(getElementsByTagName('regForm'))">
</form>
```

Comment: опечатка вот тут: `name = " "` должно быть `==`.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, исправил. Но проблема не решилась . Всё равно по нажатию на кнопку с пустым полем имени alert не выскакивает

Comment: все зависит от кнопки которую нажали. если это cancel То результатом будет null а не пустая строка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `name` и `tagName` - разные вещи.

```
onclick="valid(document.getElementById('regForm'))"
```

Не говоря уже о том, что `getElementsByTagName` возвращает коллекцию элементов.

Comment: спасибо, я не знал этого

Answer (score 1):

1. в услвои должно быть сравнение и пишется "==", а у вас как равно "="
2. ошибка во втором условии у вас ссылка не верная "https//:google.com", а надо так  "https://google.com/"

P.S. Достаточно просто написать

```
if (name === ""){
    alert('Вы не ввели свое имя');
} else {
 window.location = "https://google.com/";
}
```

Comment: не совсем подходит, т.к. дальше будет валидация других полей и с переменной нужно делать. Но суть не в этом - всё равно не работает ничего. При нажатии на кнопку с незаполненным именем - ничего не происходит на странице. alert не выскакивает

Comment: А ошибка какая то есть вообще ? мб скрипт вылитает раньше чем доходит до вашей проверки.

Comment: ошибка была в неверной ссылке на форму getElementsByTagName('regForm')

Answer (score 0):

Поменял имя входной переменной функции (понятия не имею почему не нравилось прежнее) и всё заработало (странно, но все же). html без изменений, вот js:

```
function valid(form){
var error = false;
var name = form.name.value;
var pass = form.password.value;
var rePass = form.rePassword.value;
var email = form.email.value;
var gender = form.gender.value;

if (name == "" || name == " "){
error ="Вы не ввели свое имя";
}
if (error) {
alert(error);
}else{
window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
}
}
```